# Set variable for drupal 9 website

Tags: hooks, 9, event-subscribers

I need to get the hostname and then define a variable which is going to be used in all controllers of the website. I am able to call the code in controller as follows:

```
$host = \Drupal::request()->getHost();
\Drupal::logger('host')->notice($host);

switch($host)
{
  case 'A';
    $var = "A";
    break;
  case 'B';
    $var = "B";
    break;
  case 'C';
    $var = "C";
    break;
  case 'D';
    $var = "D";
    break;
  default;
    $var = "";
    break;
}
```

But instead of defining it in all Controllers, I want to define it at a very beginning, then create a global variable(eg. $var) which I would be able to call in all controllers.
I need to know which hook or event would help me in this scenario.

Comment: Create a service with a function returning your variable: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8#s-defining-services-by-fully-qualified-name-of-php-namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to define it at a very beginning, then create a global variable(eg. $var) which I would be able to call in all controllers.

Defining a global variable for this use case is bad practice, and should be avoided.

Instead, you should create a custom service which [injects the `request_stack` service](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8), and provides a method to get your host variable based on that.

Then inject your custom service into each of your controllers, and make use of that method to get the variable.